# Match range for value with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a campaign collection, which is for advertisers. It's schema is:

```
var campaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  sponsor: String,

  [...]

  target: {
    age: {
      lower: Number,
      upper: Number
    },
    gender: String,
    locations: Array, // [ { radius: '', lon: '', lat: '' } ]
    activities: Array 
  }
});
```

I need to run a query with a specific age, and return all campaigns where that age is between `age.lower` and `age.higher`.

I have read the docs for `$gt` and `$lt`, however they appear to only work one way (so I could specify a range and match a value, however I need to specify a value and match a range).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a query on the lower bound of that value, sort the results in descending order and get the top document from the result. Compare that document with the upper bound, if there is a match then that document has a range which contains that age. For example:

```
var age = 23;
var ads = db.campaign.find({ "age.lower": {"$lte": age } }).sort({"age.lower": -1}).limit(1);

if (ads != null) {
    var result = ads[0];
    if (result.age.upper > age) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood the problem, I got it now.

```
db.collection.find( { "age.lower": { $lt: value1 }, "age.upper": { $gt: value1 } } );
```

So, for example, if your range is 25 to 40, and value1 is 30, 25 < 30 and 40 > 30 -- match!

If you use the same range with 20, 25 !< 20 -- will not match.